# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythtb' in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to get this package [PythonTB](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/pythtb/index.html) to run in Jupyter Notebook. I installed it using these [instructions](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/pythtb/install.html). It seems to work when I download a sample.py file, but in the Jupyter Notebook, I get this when I import the package:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythtb'

I'm not sure why this is happening. Could anyone please help out? Thanks.

Comment: If you used pip to install the package then make sure Jupyter is using the same Python interpreter - type `!which python` in a Jupyter cell to see which Python interpreter it's using

Comment: @TobyPetty That gives: ' 'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.' as the output. 
However, I can just do import sys and sys.version to find that it's running 3.7.3. 
When I put 'python --version' in CMD, I get 3.7.7. So, there is a difference in the version. Is this the issue? If so, how do I get Jupyter to run the latest one automatically?

Comment: Sorry - `which` is a Unix command so would not work on Windows. It's not the version of Python which is important but the path to the actual interpreter itself; basically are you sure that the package is installed in the same version of Python that Jupyter is using. If you use virtual environments or use Jupyter through something like Anaconda, then the most likely explanation for the error is that you installed the package in a different version of Python to the one that Jupyter is using.

Comment: @TobyPetty A simple conda update python seemed to solve the issue.